# Opening new window from Angular JS controller and passing the parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am opening a new window by reloading the separate URL from my angularJS application controller, both of these URL share the same application controller however being referred by different URL.

While opening the URL in new tab using window.open i want to send some parameters from first window, i am trying to set it up in $scope or $rootscope but that is coming as undefined.

Is there any way by which i can set the parameters from one page to another so that it is available to new window.

I tried multiple methods to make it working but in vain, i also try to set parameter in window.opener but no result.

```
                                 }
```

i expect that scope or rootscope should have value in new window, which is missing

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` and `$rootscope` doesn't sharing between windows.

You can save data to the `localstorage` before call the `window.open` and in new window get data from the `localstorage`.

Or you can pass some parameters from `$scope` as URL Parameters and in window read it from URL.